# advice for login with robospice?

Tags: android, spring, authentication, robospice

I'm new to using android with webservices, im using the robospice library, but i dont understand well how does `robospice` work to send and receive data from the web service. in the example (with `spring`) on the [github page](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Starter-Guide) 
it uses classes follower and List follower. List follower has this code inside:

```
public class FollowerList extends ArrayList<Follower> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8192333539004718470L;
}
```

and i have no idea of what it is for,how can i adapt the code for a login?
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question. The serialVersionUID is however not used for login and serves a completely different purpose. For login, you should research on topics like Spring Security.

I think the example is an old example and the serialVersionUID actually doesn't impact the running of the example.

For example, if you had excluded the line:

```
public class FollowerList extends ArrayList<Follower> {
/*    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8192333539004718470L;*/
}
```

The example still runs perfectly. Also if you go "Find Usage" on serialVersionUID on android studios, you will see that none of the classes actually use this static variable.

The only explanation I have for this is it was there so that someone could get a handle on the FollowerList to manipulate it at one point in time on the android/client side. It is not used in the network communication or in the server side communication with the github api.